# do_rootfs function failed in yocto project

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-16.04, embedded-linux, yocto

I am just getting started with the yocto project and trying to build an image for x86 architecture to be emulated using QEMU emulator (running on Ubuntu 16.04 ).I am getting the following error while building the OS image.

```
ERROR: core-image-sato-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:do_rootfs(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass', lineno: 258, function: do_rootfs
     0254:    progress_reporter.next_stage()
     0255:
     0256:    # generate rootfs
     0257:    d.setVarFlag('REPRODUCIBLE_TIMESTAMP_ROOTFS', 'export', '1')
 *** 0258:    create_rootfs(d, progress_reporter=progress_reporter, logcatcher=logcatcher)
     0259:
     0260:    progress_reporter.finish()
     0261:}
     0262:do_rootfs[dirs] = "${TOPDIR}"
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/rootfs.py', lineno: 1010, function: create_rootfs
     1006:    env_bkp = os.environ.copy()
     1007:
     1008:    img_type = d.getVar('IMAGE_PKGTYPE')
     1009:    if img_type == "rpm":
 *** 1010:        RpmRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
     1011:    elif img_type == "ipk":
     1012:        OpkgRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
     1013:    elif img_type == "deb":
     1014:        DpkgRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/rootfs.py', lineno: 201, function: create
     0197:        if self.progress_reporter:
     0198:            self.progress_reporter.next_stage()
     0199:
     0200:        # call the package manager dependent create method
 *** 0201:        self._create()
     0202:
     0203:        sysconfdir = self.image_rootfs + self.d.getVar('sysconfdir')
     0204:        bb.utils.mkdirhier(sysconfdir)
     0205:        with open(sysconfdir + "/version", "w+") as ver:
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/rootfs.py', lineno: 450, function: _create
     0446:        rpm_pre_process_cmds = self.d.getVar('RPM_PREPROCESS_COMMANDS')
     0447:        rpm_post_process_cmds = self.d.getVar('RPM_POSTPROCESS_COMMANDS')
     0448:
     0449:        # update PM index files
 *** 0450:        self.pm.write_index()
     0451:
     0452:        execute_pre_post_process(self.d, rpm_pre_process_cmds)
     0453:
     0454:        if self.progress_reporter:
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/package_manager.py', lineno: 543, function: write_index
     0539:
     0540:    def write_index(self):
     0541:        lockfilename = self.d.getVar('DEPLOY_DIR_RPM') + "/rpm.lock"
     0542:        lf = bb.utils.lockfile(lockfilename, False)
 *** 0543:        RpmIndexer(self.d, self.rpm_repo_dir).write_index()
     0544:        bb.utils.unlockfile(lf)
     0545:
     0546:    def insert_feeds_uris(self, feed_uris, feed_base_paths, feed_archs):
     0547:        from urllib.parse import urlparse
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/package_manager.py', lineno: 105, function: write_index
     0101:        else:
     0102:            signer = None
     0103:
     0104:        createrepo_c = bb.utils.which(os.environ['PATH'], "createrepo_c")
 *** 0105:        result = create_index("%s --update -q %s" % (createrepo_c, self.deploy_dir))
     0106:        if result:
     0107:            bb.fatal(result)
     0108:
     0109:        # Sign repomd
File: '/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/lib/oe/package_manager.py', lineno: 21, function: create_index
     0017:def create_index(arg):
     0018:    index_cmd = arg
     0019:
     0020:    bb.note("Executing '%s' ..." % index_cmd)
 *** 0021:    result = subprocess.check_output(index_cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
     0022:    if result:
     0023:        bb.note(result)
     0024:
     0025:"""
File: '/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py', lineno: 626, function: check_output
     0622:        # empty string. That is maintained here for backwards compatibility.
     0623:        kwargs['input'] = '' if kwargs.get('universal_newlines', False) else b''
     0624:
     0625:    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
 *** 0626:               **kwargs).stdout
     0627:
     0628:
     0629:class CompletedProcess(object):
     0630:    """A process that has finished running.
File: '/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py', lineno: 708, function: run
     0704:            raise
     0705:        retcode = process.poll()
     0706:        if check and retcode:
     0707:            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
 *** 0708:                                     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
     0709:    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
     0710:
     0711:
     0712:def list2cmdline(seq):
Exception: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/rahul/poky/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/createrepo_c --update -q /home/rahul/poky/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo' returned non-zero exit status 1

Subprocess output:
Temporary repodata directory /home/rahul/poky/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/.repodata/ already exists! (Another createrepo process is running?)

ERROR: core-image-sato-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rahul/poky/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.5019
ERROR: Task (/home/rahul/poky/poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Build process runs upto almost 90 percent after which this error comes up which terminates the process.What could be the issue ?

Comment: `createrepo_c` tool fails with `core-image-sato/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/.repodata/ already exists! (Another createrepo process is running?)`. Do you have any qemu instance already running? Try to remove that `.repodata` folder and build again?

Comment: There was one just rpm directory in the given path and nothing as .repodata folder.I removed that directory but still it comes up with same error.

Comment: What is your Yocto version?

Comment: Maybe ask this question on [mailing-list](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/listinfo/poky) or irc [#yocto](https://webchat.freenode.net/)

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when my host machine shut down abruptly, but everything worked well after I delete the `.repodata` folder with `sudo rm -r build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/.repodata/` and then build again.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped a build using Ctrl-C and got the python error described in the original question.

The .repodata folder (please see the answer from jmiranda) was empty. So I deleted the oe-rootfs-repo folder and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue, but with error "Directory not empty" instead, when building in Docker container. Deleting the destination directory using rm -r, and running the build again, works.

Answer (score 1):

None of these methods worked for me.

I then clean the build using `bitbake -c clean mybuildname` and then again made the build and it worked flawlessly, i hope it helps someone.